# timeout vs. time-out vs. time out in British English

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, british-english, style

I have a term called `time out` which refers to the maximum amount of time the program will wait for a response, after which it will close the connection. I do not know how to spell it. There is the choice of `timeout` as a single word, `time out` as two words, and `time-out`. which one is more correct in the British English academic writing style?

Comment: You seem to be extending the Full Oxford English dictionary definition **timeout** *(Computing and Electronics) A **cancellation** or **pausing of an operation** which occurs automatically after a preset time interval, esp. if a particular signal is not detected* to mean ***the duration of inactivity*** that triggers the cancellation. I doubt "British English academic writing style" would have much to say about such domain-specific technical usages, but I'm sure ***timeout** threshold [value]* would be much more common orthography than the hyphenated or two-word alternatives there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a verb I would use two words, this allows for the verb endings to be added easily.

> My connection timed out after 30 seconds.

As a noun I would use a compound word:

> We should increase the timeout to 45 seconds.

Using a hyphen would be an entirely acceptable alternative.

> I agree. A 30-second time-out is too short.